# How to debug OpenSSL C program using Eclipse to learn flow of program

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, debugging, debug-symbols

I have downloaded the OpenSSL source file as well as install it using the source. Now I want to debug a C program using OpenSSL shared library to learn flow of program.

I am using Eclipse with CDT .

Here is my questions

1. How to copy the openssl source file into Eclipse ? Is it just to copy the openssl folder into src folder in my eclipse project or Something else?
2. Right now if I use debugger , it don't go inside the function although I am using break point at that line of function .
3. I have tried this method also- use printf statement inside source files ( inside function definition)of openssl  and reinstall it again , follow same steps again , but when I run it, I am expecting the display of my customized message while my function is called , but the messages are not displayed . It means my functions are not called (Or atleast my printf is not added while installing modified openssl ) although I am getting result of that function.

Do I need to use printk (use for kernel module)????

Thanks in advance. I am using gcc under linux.

Comment: Shall we assume you mean the `libcrypto`component of the OpenSSL package, some other lib, or the actual command-line utility (the latter seeming somewhat a long stretch, granted).

Comment: @Whozcraig, I am initially looking into libcrypto component of OpenSSL package . I am doing an simple encryption/decryption using aes.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the question is quite old. However, I just had the same issue and hope that this answer is useful to other people in the future.

Ad question 1: Import openssl as C project into Eclipse (File -> Import -> C/C++ -> Existing code as Makefile project)

Ad question 2: You need to build openssl with debug symbols:

```
$ ./config -d
$ make
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile OpenSSL in debug mode and choose *Makefile Project with Existing Code* in Eclipse.

Here is a summary of the steps:

## OpenSSL

```
$ ./config --debug --prefix=/tmp/openssl -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'

$ make

$ make install
```

## Eclipse

Go to *File | New | Project* and choose *Makefile Project with Existing Code*.

Source: https://mathieularose.com/how-to-debug-openssl-with-eclipse/